# How to make a Curl call in node.js with arguments

Tags: javascript, node.js, curl, cloudant

I am trying to make this curl request from a node module. not sure how to pass the arguments.

```
curl -u myusername https://myusername.cloudant.com/_api/v2/monitoring/disk_use?cluster=myclustername&format=json
```

so far I got the following code. I am using `node-libcurl` in hopes that it would be easy.

```
    var Curl = require( 'node-libcurl' );
    var curl = new Curl();


    curl.setOpt( 'URL', 'myusername.cloudant.com/_api/v2/monitoring/disk_use?cluster=myclustername&format=json' );

curl.on( 'end', function( statusCode, body, headers ) {

        console.info( statusCode );
        console.info( '---' );
        console.info( body );
        console.info( '---' );
        console.info( this.getInfo( 'TOTAL_TIME' ) );

        this.close();
    });
```

So I don't know how to pass the -u flag in the command. Thanks in advance any direction would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set username and password by:

```
curl.setOpt( Curl.option.USERNAME, 'username' );
curl.setOpt( Curl.option.PASSWORD, 'password' );
```

Reference: https://github.com/JCMais/node-libcurl/blob/develop/examples/email-retrieve.js

Comment: I tried this. it doesn't work because I need to pass a -u flag. There's no USERNAME auth option.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [curl examples](https://github.com/JCMais/node-libcurl/tree/master/examples)

```
curl.setOpt( Curl.option.USERNAME, 'username' );
curl.setOpt( Curl.option.PASSWORD, 'password' );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) package from NPM. check [HTTP Authentication](https://github.com/request/request#http-authentication) section on Github.