# Convert Curl with arguments to Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, curl, cloudant

I have the following Curl command that I am trying to convert to node.js

```
curl -u myusername https://myusername.cloudant.com/_api/v2/monitoring/disk_use?cluster=myclustername&format=json
```

this returns an array in the terminal when executed. which is what I need.
Now I have tried to convert this to Node.js. here's my code

```
var request = require('request');
var user = 'myusername'
var options = {
    url: 'https://myusername.cloudant.com/_api/v2/monitoring/disk_use?cluster=myclustername&format=json',
body: user
};

function callback(error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        console.log(body);
    }
}

request(options, callback);
```

this when executed gives me an authentication error. Because `-u` is not being passed before the url. I was wondering how could I pass that -u parameter. Any help would be extremely appreciated.

Comment: [An answer to your question from yesterday](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38400679/893780) suggested that you take a look [at the `request` documentation on HTTP authentication](https://github.com/request/request#http-authentication). Did you?

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to set the username and password for basic auth, then you can see an example for how to do that here:  https://github.com/request/request#http-authentication

```
request.get('http://some.server.com/', {
  'auth': {
    'user': 'username',
    'pass': 'password'
  }
});
```

The username and password can also be put into the URL per the format in [RFC 1738](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt).